# Can't install php-mysql module

Tags: php5, php

First time using php 5.5 and well I'm getting a lot of headaches.

I can't install `php-mysql`, I get the following error:

```
Error: Package: php-mysql-5.4.30-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
       Requires: php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.4.30-1.el6.remi
       Installed: php-pdo-5.5.14-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
           php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.5.14-2.el6.remi
       Available: php-pdo-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
           php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.3.3-26.el6
       Available: php-pdo-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
           php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5
       Available: php-pdo-5.4.29-3.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.4.29-3.el6.remi
       Available: php-pdo-5.4.30-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.4.30-1.el6.remi
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

What do I do?

Comment: you have Installed: php-pdo-5.5.14 from @remi-php55

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to enable the `remi-php55` repository from which you intended to get the packages.

You should make this persistent by editing the repo configuration file `/etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo` and ensuring that the `remi` and `remi-php55` repos are enabled.

Comment: +1, correct, you've enabled remi but not the sub-repositories. You could also uninstall remi mysql and install the standard mysql and just rely on centos / epel, but remi's packages will work too.