# Can't Install mcrypt for CentOS 7 Using php-common-5.4.16

Tags: php, centos7, php-mcrypt

I've tried installing mcrypt and I'm receiving an error (below). Basically the error says I have the wrong version of PHP (as far as I can tell). I've seen a similar post here:

[Can't install php-mysql module](https://serverfault.com/questions/614010/cant-install-php-mysql-module)

But I'm not clear on how (if possible) to re-mediate this issue and get mcrypt installed.

I've checked a number of sources for how to install php-mcrypt; an example would be:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919595/how-to-install-mcrypt-php-extension-on-centos-7-0-x64

The error I am getting:

```
[root@blogs-etal-1 steinholland.com]# sudo yum -y install php-mcrypt
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.nac.net
 * epel: mirrors.mit.edu
 * extras: mirror.cc.columbia.edu
 * remi-safe: remi.mirrors.cu.be
 * updates: linux.cc.lehigh.edu
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.3.3-4.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20090626 for package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20090626 for package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmcrypt.so.4()(64bit) for package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-4.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libmcrypt.x86_64 0:2.5.8-9.el6 will be installed
---> Package php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.3.3-4.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20090626 for package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20090626 for package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-4.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-4.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: php(api) = 20090626
           Installed: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.3.x86_64 (@base)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64 (base)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
Error: Package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-4.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Installed: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.3.x86_64 (@base)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64 (base)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running CentOS 7, but you installed EPEL for CentOS 6. This obviously is not going to work. Remove it and reinstall EPEL for CentOS 7.

```
yum reinstall epel-release
```

Comment: says: Package epel-release-7-5.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

Comment: You still need to get rid of the EPEL 6 repository. And probably clean metadata.

Comment: Misunderstood how to remove it; ran this to remove it:  yum remove epel-release and that solved it!